# xCode: This app can not be installed at this time. Only get this error after adding the watchOS extension

Tags: xcode

App runs perfectly fine before adding the watchOS extension. But when I add it, it refuses to install the main app when I run it.

Things I've tried: 
- clean, re-build
- reinstalled pods
- checked log file (gave me no useful info on what was happening)
- scrubbed every link I could find on google and found nothing that worked.

Any help?

Comment: Restart Xcode yet?  This can fix app install errors.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up codesigning for the extension?
What message appears in your the system log of the device under test when the install fails?